# Extracting issue of high size zip files to google colab

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory

We're indie game development team which working on a rogue-like game. And due to lackness of animation expert we need to use ubisoft latest AI solution. To handle that we moved related files to the google colab but we could not extract no matter how many times we tried. Can anybody help us who experienced this issue before?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vqizh.png)

Github link: https://github.com/ubisoft/ubisoft-laforge-ZeroEGGS

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
!pip install dtrx
!dtrx Zeggs_data.zip
```

Comment: `Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Requirement already satisfied: dtrx in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (8.4.0)
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv`

Colab also gives this error now
It gives such an error in the code you shared

Comment: @Bünyamin Efe It's just a warning. Did you check if the files were extracted?

Comment: yes I checked but it didn't get the output

Comment: Here is a test that worked well for me: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1vqG8WHiT_UYGsLYSUg24gLrUYJ4YaYHY?usp=sharing